# Firemonkey Error running lib/gdbserver: couldn't reserve XXX bytes of address space at XXX for

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am using Delphi 10.4 with patch 3

It happens when trying to debug the app (without debugger the app works fine)

[image]

Comment: Not enough memory in the device to run the debugger?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm getting the same error on Delphi 11.2 and cant find a solution for it

Answer (score -1):

@Miguel - Please check the quality central. As far as I remember, there were some issues reported for 10.4.x while debugger is on.